# Appropriate test to compare frequency of events against expected

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Suppose I'm expecting something to happen periodically, with data being randomly sampled from a stream. The random sampling would result in the distribution of times to be a geometric distribution.

What would be the appropriate way to tell if the sample is different from what is expected? Eg. Compute the mean, use a T-test? Use the KS test? Compare count directly with a Chi-squared test? How would each test affect the test statistic? Is there any way I can control the sensitivity of the test?

Edit:
More concrete information -

Every X minute, I'm randomly deciding whether to query a server for processes running on it. The goal is to decide is a certain process is running in the pattern I expect (eg once every Y minute).

Comment: Because the question is framed so abstractly, it is hard to determine what it's about.  It is very strange to design a sampling program where the times have a geometric distribution!  How does this arise?  Would you detect the periodic event only when sampling, or would sampling indicate that the event had occurred at least once since the last sampling event?  Can successive events be considered independent?  Could you describe the problem you actually face, in your own terms?

Comment: @whuber. Essentially it's expensive to sample the stream, so every couple of minutes, it's randomly decided whether to sample the stream. The time between samples would thus be a geometric distribution due to the way sampling is set up.

Comment: Thank you--I should have figured that out.  It's an interesting design.  But what about my other questions about the type of event you are looking for and its detectability and independence?  You could explain a lot merely by telling us what this event actually is and what your sample measures.

Comment: @whuber. Sampling detects whether a number of events are occurring at the time of sampling, and these events occur periodically in the ideal case. The goal would be to tell if the events are actually period based on sample results

Comment: What's an "event"?  Are you counting something?  Are the things you are counting independent or not?  Can a given "event" show up in successive samples?  Do you have any hypotheses about the likely periods?  How does the question of periodicity relate to the stated question, which is about frequencies?

Comment: Ah sorry, I probably used the wrong word. The events may or may not be independent (I'm essentially monitoring traffic) My hypothesis would be say the event happens every minute, but it's possible that that's not happening, or something else might trigger the event, which is something I'm trying to detect.

Comment: Until you disclose what you're actually measuring and why, it is going to be difficult to formulate or justify any good answers.

Comment: Well concretely there's a server somewhere that I can query to know what's running on it. I expect something to be running process A on that server periodically, but other things could cause process A to run too. I basically want to tell though sampling if process A is running at the frequency I expect.

Comment: That helps.  But by "frequency" would you mean *proportion of the time* or would you be referring to testing whether it is truly periodic, as in a sine wave pattern?  And what is this frequency measuring: actual calendar time during which the process is running or the number of times it is invoked or proportion of computing resources it is utilizing (or something else)?

Comment: It's something that's scheduled to run in a pattern. Ideally I would be able to test if it matches the exact pattern, so test if it's truly periodic. I image that the proportion of time could be used too? That's my main confusion and why I posted - I'm not sure of the difference the different tests/measure makes.

Comment: Because few people will take the time and effort to parse through these comments, it would be well to edit your post to include all this additional (and very useful) information.  I think there's now enough to prompt qualified readers to suggest useful solutions.